# Project extension with invalid name found in Angular with NX

Tags: angular, typescript, nrwl-nx

I am using `Angular` with `nx` and when I try to `nx serve todos` I get this error:

```
Project extension with invalid name found
```

And my project name is: `todos`.

I followed this https://nx.dev/angular-tutorial/01-create-application to create `todos` app with `Angular 14.0.5` and I get the above error.

Does someone have any idea regarding this error?

Comment: If you are using vscode, you can try out the nx dashboard extension. There is a commands section where you can choose to serve whichever app you want in the workspace.

Comment: What is the effective name of your angular app ? Todos or myapp ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a git issue (see [this](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/11138)) regarding to this problem. It's something that started to appear in Angular `CLI v14.0.6`.

Based on the git issue they are currently working on that to solve the problem
but the most important thing is that: **it doesn't really cause any issues apart from the noisy logs**.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with angular `nx` and I looked for solution and found a git issue describing the same problem and there it was written that "When starting the Angular app with `nx` run `portal:serve:development` the project compiles successfully, though there is some noisy logging. This is a known issue with `Nx` with the newest version of Angular. It is said to be harmless.

`nrwl/nx#11138`

As the known issue is harmless I think there is no need to worry about this issue.

I am attaching the git page link below:
https://github.com/ZenSoftware/zen/issues/21

Answer (score 1):

When I have ran this command  `npm run affected:test --code-coverage` I got below warning :

> Project 'user-journey' contains extension with invalid name (tags).

For fixing this warning, I have removed below line from nx.json / angular.json

```
"defaultProject": "web-shell",
```

Key **defaultProject** has been deprecated.

Please refer this link : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11111